# What is the name of this flowering tree?

Tags: identification, trees, flowers, planting

I need help to identify the following tree. It is commonly seen in Hong Kong. However，I can't find it when searching for it under the common trees in Hong Kong. What is the name of the tree?

[image: tree identification]

Comment: Looks a little like a cherry tree to me, but it's just a guess.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like Bougainvillea sp. from the picture. It's a common ornamental vine in the sub-tropics. The pink leak-like bracts are not the flowers. The true flowers are the small button like tips in the middle. Hundreds of varieties in different sizes and colors are available.

Comment: Most Bougainvillea have sharp thorns, My best guess from the image would be an ornamental apple (Malus) - can you take a close-up of the flowers

Comment: You can zoom in on the picture, and it looks right! Bougainvillea are a common ornamental plant and they are renowned for their nasty, nasty thorns that can easily go through your average shoe. They are often used in desert landscapes because they are extremely hardy (and even difficult to kill on purpose!) and require very little water. Their flowers are papery and typically have three 'petals'.